# Pika - Rabbitmq, using Basic.get to cosume single message from queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm using the method shown [here](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/blocking_basic_get.html) like this:
`while method_frame is None:
    method_frame, header_frame, method_frame= channel.basic.get("test_queue)`

It's looks like this polling is not so efficient this way, because basic get is working also if queue is empty, and bringing empty messages.

I need a kind of logic which takes a single message, only when I have the opportunity to take care of it, that's why I chose `basic.get` and not `basic.consume`.

Do anybody has and idea for doing a more efficient polling maybe by using some pika's library other mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using basic.consume(ack=true) with basic.qos(prefetch_count=1).

You need to see how to do that with your particular library

Comment: Hi can you please explain its meaning  with more detail, ack=True and what is basiq.qos(prefetch_count=1)?

Comment: In addition do you know how to do it with pika library?

Comment: @JavaSa this is explained on the RabbitMQ tutorials http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

Comment: another thing, if I want to use basic_get instead when multiple consumers are bind to the same queue, and I want only one to get the message not all of them, is it possible?